# Tangent at $0$ of $\sqrt{|x|}$

Tags: calculus, limits

This is a question regarding the solution to a question from Adams' book on Calculus. The question asks whether the function $f(x) = \sqrt{|x|}$ has a tangent line at $x = 0$. The answer is no. But when looking through the solution manual, Adams reasons like this. He writes:

> Since $\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \dfrac{\sqrt{|0+h|}-0}{h} = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \dfrac{1}{|h|\operatorname{sgn}{(h)}}$ does not exist…

My question is about this equality. The limit expressions are not equal, even close to $0$, for example at $h=\frac{1}{2}$.

Is this a typo? Is this some property of limits I don't know about? My own calculations led me to the first limit  equalling $\frac{1}{\sqrt{|h|}}\text{sgn}{(h)}$ which also shows that the limit doesn't exist (right?). But it doesn't explain Adams' answer. And specifically, is there some situation where I can "remove roots" in this way? What if the limit did exist?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There must be a typo in the manual. Your solution is indeed correct and, as you pointed out, yields the correct answer.

Comment: Also I don't agree with the answer. A tangent line at $x=0$ exists, namely: a vertical one. The question is not about differentiability.

Comment: @Adayah Adams defines a tangent line to a function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, at the point $x_0$, as a line passing through the point $(x_0, f(x_0)) $ with slope given by the limit above, with provisions made for limits unambiguously equalling $\infty$ and $-\infty$, when the tangent is vertical. If the limit fails to exist in any other way, there is no tangent line. In what sense is the tangent vertical at $x = 0$?

Comment: It approximates the graph up to a term quadratic in the distance from $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you pointed out...

$$
\frac{\sqrt{|h|}}{h}=\frac{\text{sgn}(h)\sqrt{|h|}}{\sqrt{|h|}\sqrt{|h|}}=\frac{\text{sgn}(h)}{\sqrt{|h|}},
$$
and the limit as $h\to 0$ from the right is $+\infty$, while the limit as $h\to 0$ from the left is $-\infty$.